# how to use image between list view items?

Tags: android, image, list, listview

i am new in android. this is my list view items code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

i want to add simple image on top of my list view
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Align the ImageView to the top or Put an ImageView BEFORE you call the ListView.

If you want the image at the top of the listview, do something similar to the following:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

If you want an image before the listview, do something similar to the following:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

<ListView
          android:id="@+id/listview_row"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     </ListView>
```